# R use %within% operator without calling library(lubridate)

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm writing a function that uses some `lubridate` functions.

However, I'm not sure how to import the function `%within%` from lubridate. Usually this is easy, as I just use lubridate::function. When I tried this with the %within% operator, this did not work. Is there any way to use operators from packages without loading the entire package itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. The issue here is that `%within%` is a special symbol that is also a function. In R, pretty much everything is a function. For example, when you do `2 + 2`, R actually interprets that as

```
`+`(2, 2)
```

Check [this section from "Advanced R"](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#function-forms) by Hadley Wickham to understand this details.

So the most direct answer to your question would be: use the same logic for the `%within%` function, but escaping the `%` symbol and directly specifying arguments a and b for the function.

```
lubridate::`%within%`(a, b)
```

If you're developing a package yourself, you can document your function that uses `%within%` using `roxygen2`. All you need to do is:

```
#' @title Your Nice Function
#' @description This is a description...
#' @param a Your first param
#' @param b Your second param
#' @importFrom lubridate \%within\%
your_nice_function <- function(a, b) {
...
}
```

That does it, because you're saying that this function imports the specific function `%within%` from lubridate, without loading the entire lubridate package.

However, if you just want to use the function inside a script the most "familiar" way possible, maybe the best way is to:

```
`%within%` <- lubridate::`%within%`
```

By doing so, you're essentially copying the function to a local variable of the same name.